# How to view map content stored in HazelcastLocalCacheRegionFactory

Tags: hibernate, caching, jmx, hazelcast, hibernate-cache

Is it possible to view content stored in HazelcastLocalCacheRegionFactory? For non-local cache regions are stored as distributed maps so it is possible to view their content like this (or via JMX):

`Cache cache = springCacheManager.getCache(cacheName);
 Map<Object, Object> cacheMap = (Map<Object, Object>)cache.getNativeCache();`

JMX also doesn't show content stored in HazelcastLocalCacheRegionFactory.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is a direct way but if you know the names of the underlying IMaps from JMX you can request them using `HazelcastInstance::getMap` just as you would do it without Hibernate.

Comment: Yes, but the problem is that HazelcastLocalCacheRegionFactory doesn't store cache data as IMaps

Comment: Oh I see it is a CHM and uses ITopic to distribute updates... I guess then you can just use Reflection to access it.